# com.hazelcast.core.DuplicateInstanceNameException HazelcastInstance with name already exists

Tags: spring, hazelcast

I am getting this error while integrating Spring with Hazelcast.
Please see my hazelcast configuration in spring-servelt.xml.
Error occurs when i Autowired Hazelcast.
Please help.

### **Hazel case Configuration in Spring.xml**

```
<hz:hazelcast id="srmsCacheInstance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:instance-name>trunk</hz:instance-name>
        <hz:group name="trunk" password="trunk" />
        <hz:management-center enabled="false" url="http://127.0.0.1:8080/mancenter-3.2.1" />
        <hz:properties>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.logging.type">log4j</hz:property>
        </hz:properties>
        <hz:network port="5701" port-auto-increment="true">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="true" multicast-group="224.2.2.3" multicast-port="54333" />
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>
        <hz:map name="srmsCache" read-backup-data="false">
            <hz:near-cache in-memory-format="OBJECT" cache-local-entries="true" />
        </hz:map>
        <hz:map name="cache.graph.tx" eviction-policy="LRU" eviction-percentage="30" read-backup-data="true" />
        <hz:map name="cache.graph.no.tx" eviction-policy="LRU" eviction-percentage="30" read-backup-data="true" />
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>
```

### **Autowired in Service Class**

```
@DefaultCustomService("defaultCachingService")
public class DefaultCachingService {
private HazelcastInstance hazelcast;
    @Autowired
    public void setHazelcast(HazelcastInstance hazelcast) {
    //  Hazelcast.shutdownAll();
        this.hazelcast = hazelcast;
    }
    protected HazelcastInstance hazelcast() {
        return hazelcast;
    }
    public Object getCachedValue(String mapKey, String cacheKey) throws Exception {
        return hazelcast().getMap(mapKey).get(cacheKey);
    }
    public Object deleteCachedValue(String mapKey, String cacheKey) throws Exception {
        return hazelcast().getMap(mapKey).remove(cacheKey);
    }
}
```

### **Following error is coming when i start the server**

Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance]: Factory method 'newHazelcastInstance' threw exception; nested exception is com.hazelcast.core.DuplicateInstanceNameException: HazelcastInstance with name 'trunk' already exists!
    at

Regards,
mmanish

Comment: Sure that you don't try to create the same instance twice?

Comment: Yes ,Sure  I am not creating the same instance twice.I have posted the code above.There is only one class where I am auto-wiring the hazelcast instance.

Comment: Problem is resolved. A listener ContextLoaderListener was configured in the web.xml and due to this context was loaded twice.

Comment: Ah great, glad you found it :)